# What is the meaning of “grosser sense” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What does *grosser sense* mean in this passage from *Mortal Immortal* by Mary Shelley?

> A bright flash darted before my eyes. I had forgotten the medicine of the adept; I gazed on it with wonder: flashes of admirable beauty, more bright than those which the diamond emits when the sun’s rays are on it, glanced from the surface of the liquid; an odour the most fragrant and grateful stole over my sense; the vessel seemed one globe of living radiance, lovely to the eye, and most inviting to the taste. The first thought, instinctively inspired by the **grosser sense**, was, I will—I must drink. I raised the vessel to my lips. “It will cure me of love—of torture!” Already I had quaffed half of the most delicious liquor ever tasted by the palate of man, when the philosopher stirred. I started—I dropped the glass—the fluid flamed and glanced along the floor, while I felt Cornelius’s grip at my throat, as he shrieked aloud, “Wretch! you have destroyed the labour of my life!”

Comment: *Gross* here is merely used in an adjectival function to modify *sense.* See **gross** (*adj.* grosser, grossest) **3 c.** Lacking sensitivity or discernment; unrefined: **d.** Carnal; sensual. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gross *cf.* **baser instincts**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Grosser sense* refers to physical desire or appetite, untempered by spiritual or rational considerations.

It looked beautiful and smelled delicious, so she drank it, without stopping to think whether it was a smart thing to do, or an ethical.

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: OTOH, there's also a 'grosser sense' applied to meanings of words/expressions.